# Network link between multiple VirtualBox machines

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am trying out a conferencing application (BigBlueButton).

For this I created an Ubuntu virtual machine that functions as the application server. On this machine I can test the application by navigating to the app url (for example http://10.0.2.15).

I also created a second virtual machine that should function as a client. On this machine I want to be able to navigate to the server as well, but that doesn't seem to be working. If I try to navigate from the client to the server by using the app-url I get nothing, followed by a timeout.

To establish a network between the two machines I tried the following solutions:

- Create a second network adapter on each virtual machine and attach to "Host-only Adapter" with name "vboxnet0"
- Create a second adapter on each machine and attach to "Internal network" named "intnet".

I thought that either of above options would be a good solutions, but none of them works.

Can anyone help me out here?

FYI I am using MacOS X as host system.

EDIT:
I created my second machine by cloning the first one (using the clone utility). Maybe this causes both machines to be identical which makes them indistinguishable on a network. Would this cause a problem? (As a desktop developer I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to I.T.)

Comment: does 10.0.2.15 fits your LAN address scheme?

Comment: have you used NAT to interwork your VM on the LAN?

Comment: I'm not sure if that address fits my LAN address scheme, how do I check? I machines use NAT as their first network adapter, so I have internet access.

Answer (score 14):

I just got this to work. What I did was the internal network with the tasteful name on both VMs, but THEN I went to Advanced and set the Promiscuous Mode to "Allow All". I connect just fine now. Try it!

OK, just looked at the dates and it was last updated 2009, but for anyone looking for the answer, here you go!

Answer (score 3):

Set the interfaces you created to internal networking. Choose a tasteful and interesting name, like "mynet". Use that name as the network name for both of the virtual machines and they will automatically be able to talk to each other over those interfaces.

---

Sorry, I see you already did that. In this case just give those two machines static IP addresses on the interfaces of "internal networking" type. Like, 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3.

Also, once you've changed the IPs make sure the server is listening on the right interface.

Answer (score 3):

IF you cloned the machine and didn't change the ip, they will never connect...
Also - make sure there is something listening on the url that you're trying to reach.
each machine should have a different ip
(but on the same network of-course)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is long overdue... But I just got mine set up and am able to ping each virtual machine from one another.

Assuming you're running [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker) like I am, simply right-click the **boot2docker** VM in VirtualBox and click clone. In the box that pops up, be sure to check the box that says "Reinitialize the MAC address of all network cards" so that the two virtual machines don't have the same MAC address.

That's it, seems to be working for me. I can ping, scan (via nmap) and even SSH into the virtual machines from one another or from my host machine.